# Problem that involves partial derivative of temperature function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

A circular piece of metal with radius $a$ has the temperature given by the following relation: for a point $(x,y)$, the temperature $T(x,y)$ is proportional to the square of the distance of this point $(x,y)$ to the center of the piece of metal, with constant of proportionality $k>0$.

So the exercise asks the following:

a) If a particle at $(\frac{a}{2},0)$ moves to the rigth about the $x$ axis, it'll suffer temperature increase or decrease?

b) What's the rate of change in respect to $y$ at the same point? What does that mean?

Here's what I did:

a)
$$T(x,y) = k\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\implies \frac{\partial T(x,y)}{\partial x} = \frac{kx}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \implies \\  \frac{\partial T(\frac{a}{2},0)}{\partial x} = \frac{k\frac{a}{2}}{\sqrt{\frac{a}{2}}^2} = k > 0$$
therefore, there is a temperature increase

b) if I do the same for $y$, we have:

$$\frac{\partial T(\frac{a}{2},0)}{\partial x} = \frac{2y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = 0$$

therefore, there is no increase or decrease in temperature in the $y$ axis for that contains this point

Am I rigth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is easier since the square of the distance is just $x^2+y^2$.
Indeed $$\frac{\partial T}{\partial y }=2k y~~,$$ therefore in $(a/2,0)$ the rate of change of $T$ along $y$ is zero. This is because this point locally minimizes $T$ respect to displacements in the $y$ direction.

Comment: So the derivative with respect to $x$ at $(a/2,0)$ is $ak>0$?

Comment: but the question is what is the rate of change in respect to y. for me that is the partial derivative respect to y. that was what you calculated, despite you wrote $\partial/\partial x$ though...

Comment: but there are two questions, a) and b)

Comment: a) is correct,  despite you used a more complicated function than necessary I think.